# Read txt file from resources folder in sub project Spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Am trying to read a file from a subproject *sample-dfx-sbi*

file is located inside *src/main/resources* folder

exact file location is *src/main/resources/wm/device.txt*

Am using below logic to read file

```
static final ClassLoader loader = DummyClass.class.getClassLoader();

public void getData(String ip)throws IOException {

    String filepath = loader.getResource("/wm/device.txt").toString();
    System.out.println(filepath);
    File file = new File(filepath);

    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);  // exception

    ...
```

Exception:

```
jar:file:/home/user/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/sample-dfx-web/WEB-INF/lib/sample-dfx-sbi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/wm/device.txt

java.io.FileNotFoundException: jar:file:/home/user/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/sample-dfx-web/WEB-INF/lib/sample-dfx-sbi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/wm/device.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
```

When I go to above location inside workspace and extract jar file I can see wm/device.txt

Then why is file not loading ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read resource as stream when you are binding it in `JAR`.

```
public String loadResource(String filelocation) {
    if (filelocation != null && !filelocation.trim().isEmpty()) {
        try (
            InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(filelocation);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));) {

            String fileLine = "";
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

            while((fileLine = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){
                stringBuffer.append(fileLine);
            }
            return stringBuffer.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```